# Calculated in looping. Flow Power automate

Tags: calculated-columns, power-automate

when the Timesheet list Item is updated, it will calculate the hours with Name and Year/Month as validation, then the results of the calculation will be put on the Summary Hours list.

I've used various ways using power automate but it always fails, is there another way? please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5oGC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXDkb.png)

Comment: can you please describe these "various ways" and how are they're failing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.